# Assign method attribute to another method of same class

Tags: python, class, methods

Suppose I define a class as follows,

```py
class MyClass:
     def foo(self, name):
         return name + ' foo'
     def _bar(self, name):
         return name + ' bar'

     foo.bar = _bar
```

and use it as such:

```py
>>> m = MyClass()
>>> m.foo('hello')
'hello foo'
>>> m.foo.bar('hello')
TypeError: _bar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

`foo.bar` raises a `TypeError` since it gives the first argument to `self`.

I want to be able to add the `_bar` method as an attribute 'bar' to the `foo` method . And the constraint is that it must be a part of the class.

Comment: Hint: Make use of a *constructor*, specifically look into `super()` method.

Comment: Why? Function attributes are rarely used, because there is usually a much better approach to whatever problem you think you are solving.

Comment: You *did* add the `_bar` function as an attribute to the `foo` function. However, this way it won't get the instance bound.

Comment: Right now, `foo` doesn't need to be a method either, since it doesn't use `self` at all.

Answer (score 1):

In order for your second code block to run, define `MyClass` in this way:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = self.foo()

    class foo():
        def __call__(self, name):
            return name + ' foo'
        
        def bar(self, name):
            return name + ' bar'

m = MyClass()
m.foo('hello')
m.foo.bar('hello')
```

Now `foo` is not merely a method of `MyClass` but rather an inner class which is callable.

Comment: why use an inner class?

Comment: the foo class doesn't have to be inside MyClass, it's just tidier that way :)

Comment: Not really. That's a very unusual thing to do in Python. But I guess that's an opinion.

Comment: The opinion to *not* use nested classes is backed up by overwhelming consensus, though.

Answer (score 1):

Really not sure if either of these are recommendable (they feel odd to me), but as is, note that the following works:

```
In[]: m.foo.bar(m, 'hello')
Out[]: 'hello bar'
```

You can pass `m` to satisfy the `self` parameter.  You could also remove `self` from `_bar` (and then even define it outside the class):

```
def _bar(name):
     return name + ' bar'

class MyClass:
     def foo(self, name):
         return name + ' foo'
     foo.bar = _bar

#then this works:
m = MyClass()
m.foo('hello')
m.foo.bar('hello')
```

Again, this all feels odd to me, so maybe someone can comment why this is okay or bad (and I will add to this answer).

Comment: this is a good answer.  but you are missing `print()` on the return calls i.e. the last two lines of the code.

Comment: @FishingCode Sure! I just mean the run; they would give output if run in an interpreter as OP does.